# $\int_0^1e^{(ax^2 + bx)}dx$ in terms of erf

Tags: integration

I'm trying to evaluate the definite integral,

$$\int_0^1e^{(ax^2 + bx)}dx$$

in terms of the function,

$$F(z)=\int_0^ze^{p^2}dp$$

The correct answer that i'm supposed to get is, 
$$\int_0^1e^{(ax^2 + bx)}dx=\frac{e^{-\frac{b^2}{4a}}}{\sqrt{a}}[F(\frac{a+b}{\sqrt{a}})-F(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a}})] $$

However i'm getting a slightly different answer with $\frac{1}{2}$ appearing in the arguments to the function F. What I get is the below,

$$\int_0^1e^{(ax^2 + bx)}dx=\frac{e^{-\frac{b^2}{4a}}}{\sqrt{a}}[F(\frac{a+b}{2\sqrt{a}})-F(\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}})] $$

Can someone advise if i'm doing something wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: First of all, how on earth are you integrating a function over $x$ from $0$ to $1$ and getting an answer in terms of $x$?

Comment: You didn't show what you did, how to find out what you did wrong?

Comment: so sorry i made a typo, i've updated the formulas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to express your integral in terms of $F$, writing $ax^2+bx = a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 - \frac{b^2}{4a}$ gives
$$\int_0^1 e^{ax^2+bx}\, dx = e^{-\frac{b^2}{4a}} \int_0^1 e^{a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2}\, dx$$
and then substituting $p=\sqrt{a}\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)$ gives you an integral which you can express in the form $F(\beta)-F(\alpha)$ for suitable constants $\alpha, \beta$.

However, the 'correct answer' you mention seems to make no sense; what are $x$ and $t$ when the integral has constant limits?

---

**Edit:** The question has changed since I posted my answer. It seems the real problem is computing $\alpha,\beta$. Now
$$\alpha = p(0) = \frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}}, \qquad \beta = p(1) = \frac{2a+b}{2\sqrt{a}}$$

Comment: yep your steps above was exactly what i did. you see the 2a appearing in the denominator?

Comment: many thanks i got it now!

Answer (score 0):

$$
ax^2 + bx = a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^{2} - \frac{b^2}{4a}
$$
thus
$$
\mathrm{e}^{ - \frac{b^2}{4a}}\int_0^1 \mathrm{e}^{a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^{2}}dx
$$
let $p = \sqrt{a}\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)$

then we have
$$
\int_{\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}}}^{\sqrt{a}\left(1+\frac{b}{2a}\right)}\mathrm{e}^{p^2}\frac{dp}{\sqrt{a}}
$$
or
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\mathrm{e}^{ - \frac{b^2}{4a}}\left[\int_0^{\sqrt{a}\left(1+\frac{b}{2a}\right)}\mathrm{e}^{p^2}dp -\int_0^{\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}}}\mathrm{e}^{p^2}dp \right]
$$
set $s = \frac{b}{2}$ and $a = t$
we find
$$
\sqrt{a}\left(1+\frac{b}{2a}\right) = \sqrt{t}\left(1 + \frac{s}{t}\right) = \frac{s+t}{\sqrt{t}}\\
\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}} = \frac{s}{\sqrt{t}}
$$
and finally
$$
\mathrm{e}^{ - \frac{b^2}{4a}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\left[\int_0^{\frac{s+t}{\sqrt{t}}}\mathrm{e}^{p^2}dp 
-\int_0^{\frac{s}{\sqrt{t}}}\mathrm{e}^{p^2}dp \right]
$$

so your answer is out by a factor of 2 due to not setting your final version of "$x$" as $b/2$. But this is purely a game of trying to match the correct answer

Comment: ah so that's why, i got it now! tks